# BlueCove on Windows 8

Tags: java, windows-8, bluetooth, bluecove

Has anyone tried to run BlueCove on Windows 8?
I have a Win8 laptop. I tried downgrading it to Win7, but they don't support Win7 drivers.

Does the newest Snapshot allow BlueCove to be run on Win 8?

Answer (score 0):

You can use newest version(2.1.2) of Bluecove. It is not officially announced by official Bluecove team but I has native OSX 64 bit support and It could be solution for Win 8. I found this version at [Bluecove issue page](https://code.google.com/archive/p/bluecove/issues/134). Please look under Comment #21. If you want you can download it [here](http://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-attachments/bluecove/issue-134/comment-21/bluecove-2.1.2.jar).